# I'm attempting to get read the text off a website from inside my static library

Tags: c++, curl, static, lib

I have looked around and I believe I can't directly link curl into my Static Library. I've read things about merging the two libraries but I don't believe that will allow me to directly access curl from my static library. I've made a few google searches and couldn't find anything of much use. Is there a way I could do this or would I be forced to write my own implementation for reading the website? Thank you anyone that can help

Comment: Warning: cURL requires A LOT of other libraries. Often statically linking cURL is only the beginning of your adventure.